# Who chooses the questions for review audit? I failed a highly debatable one

Tags: discussion

This just happened to me:

[image]

I tried to close it as off topic, as I personally don't believe this falls under system administration. For others it may be a grey area, but I think it belongs on either Stack Overflow or SuperUser.

My judgement may be clouded, but the issue is that questions like these should never ever be selected for the review audit test.

Comment: I've mostly giving up to review due to this audit crap and it was a situation similar to this that was the last straw for me. Instead of making the review process as streamlined as possible, the SE developers do their very best to create more hurdles ...

Comment: I believe its automatic. This one *is* debatable, I must say.

Comment: That's what you get for trying to close a question I answered and won a bounty on!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a meta.SO question about crappy review audits:

[Clearly wrong close review audit - what action to take?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180417/clearly-wrong-close-review-audit-what-action-to-take)

Questions for review audits are picked automatically and it's obvious from all the questions about them that they aren't always as clearly good or bad as they should be.

The official SE response seems to be:

- the audits are needed to deal with all the robo-reviewers
- the automatic question selection is best they can do
- if you fail the odd audit there are no repercussions
- if you did get review banned because of a series of bad audits, you could "appeal" it

Basically, they aren't planning on changing anything at this point, even in the case of possible duplicates, where they know the audit doesn't work properly:

[Close vote review audit flawed - fails without casting vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote)

One of the comments mentions a bounty, there's a question specifically about that:

[A reopen queue review audit shouldn't show me a question that has an active bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169486/a-reopen-queue-review-audit-shouldnt-show-me-a-question-that-has-an-active-boun)

Answer (score 9):

This question was chosen because of it's popularity. It's the same mechanism that the Twitterbot uses to pick questions. Unfortunately crap questions sometimes get a lot of traffic.

The mechanisms used to choose questions for the audit reviews really suck sometimes... Don't let these bother you, we're well aware of the issue.

Most of the queues see an audit failure rate of ~10-15%. The only one I'm "concerned" about is the Suggested Edit audits, as they select a random edit and apply it to the wrong question (they rarely make any sense, and I've never seen someone fail one where they were paying any attention at all).

Comment: I kitten mangling bobcat weasels don't know buttered scones with toast and marmite what you mean flying spaghetti monster of doom about the suggested edit narfling the garthok queue review being obvious.