# Review "audit" seems incorrect?

Tags: support, review

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/525380/best-method-to-clone-a-windows-server) popped up in my review queue for "vote to reopen" requests.  I voted to leave it closed, and got everyone's favorite condescending warning:

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. There are no major problems with this question.

While normally I agree with these...in this case, what the heck?  The "question" has no question.  This sort of non-question gets closed all the time.

Comment: The TL;DR version: Don't worry about it, we know, you aren't penalized.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that.  I just thought that this particular audit stood out as being slightly odd.

Comment: But no worries.

Comment: It *feels* like about a third of the audits are bad. Given that they must assume that still open questions are good examples we're more likely simply missing things that *are* closable.

Comment: Hey, it was upvoted to +5..

Comment: It happens to everyone, like me: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5502/who-chooses-the-questions-for-review-audit-i-failed-a-highly-debatable-one

Answer (score 3):

This question doesn't look close-worthy at all.

Certainly it solicits the "best" method of accomplishing a reasonably normal Windows system administration task. Though, leaving aside for the moment the less than perfect word choice, this is something that is easily answerable with "facts, references or specific expertise." Best practices are "best" for a reason; while there may be more than one way to solve a problem, experience or the vendor or both will usually suggest one solution is preferred over another. The existence of best practices and/or vendor guidance for a question preclude its being "primarily opinion-based."

Sorry you failed the audit, but it appears that in this case the audit succeeded in its intent: to make sure you were paying attention.

Finally, if I'm not familiar with the subject matter, I would skip the review unless it's blatantly obvious to even a zombie...